# Proof of collar neighborhood theorem

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm trying to understand the proof of the collar neighborhood theorem given in the following document:

http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2015/lecture-nov2.pdf

At the end of the proof it says that we can argue by contradiction using the compactness of $\partial M$ to construct the desired diffeomorphism, but I don't see how too do it.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Aloizio Macedo’s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2964066/245133); their map $F$ is essentially your map $\varphi| _{[0, \epsilon) \times \partial M}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more question: in the reasoning with the sequences, when we use the compactness of $\partial M$ to find a convergence subsequent, are we implicitly using the fact that manifolds are metrizable?

Comment: Yes, because every second-countable manifold is metrizable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space), the "open cover" definition of compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano–Weierstrass_theorem#Sequential_compactness_in_Euclidean_spaces)